# sum of series independent of variable in sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

\begin{equation}
-\frac{k^2+4}{k^2-8}-\frac{12k^2}{(k^2-8)^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{k^2}{k^2-8})^n=\frac{1}{2} , -2\leq k\leq 2
\end{equation}

This is an equation which sums up to a value independent of $k$.

I am working on a problem that is generating quite a lot of such sums which ultimately end up summing to a value independent of the parameter in the sequence.

My question is: Is it common for such kind of sums to occur in literature and do they have any particular significance in any applications?

Comment: I can't answer your question, though I know about $\pi/2 = \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (\alpha x)}{x}dx$, for any $\alpha>0$.

Comment: If the sums come from study of some sort of physical system and you find a lot of the sums sum to something independent of the parameter, you system may have a hidden symmetry you haven't notice. Even for pure mathematical problem, this can happen. Let's look at the example $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\alpha x}{x}dx$ in comment above. It is independent of $\alpha$ because the "weight" $\frac{dx}{x}$ is "invariant" under scaling $x \to k x$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the question, so forgive me if I am off-topic.

If you have to compute $$S=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{k^2}{k^2-8})^n$$ just rmemember that $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n=\frac{1}{1-a}$$ which makes, using $a= \frac{k^2}{k^2-8}$ $$S=\frac{1}{8} \left(8-k^2\right)$$ From there, the remaining seems to be simple.

Comment: But $\frac{k^2}{k^2-8}>1$.

Comment: @Arian. For the  range $-2\lt k\lt 2$, $-1 <\frac{k^2}{k^2-8} \lt 0$ if I am not wrong (but I may be).

Comment: You are right. My apologies, I did not see the range.

Comment: No problem ! If I was given a cent for everything I did not see, I would be a millionaire ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics is full of clever tricks, and one of them is writing something simple as a sum of soemthing complicated. The best example I have is kind of obscure in purpose, but it involves expressing $t^m$ as
$$t^m=\sum_{A\subseteq B\subseteq C}{t^{|B|}(1-t)^{|C-B|}}$$
where $A$ and $C$ are fixed, $A$ has $m$ elements, and $B$, which is a set, is the index of summation.

Comment: Ok agreed, it is a bad example. But my question is that sums which ARE fundamentally independent of $k$, that is, they cannot be factored out in any way: Are such sums important mathematically?

Comment: @zynga Please see my edit above, hope it is closer to answering your question.

Comment: But, in this new example, neither the LHS nor the RHS are independent of the parameter 't'. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @zynga as I said in the previous answer, every sum depends on the parameter. I could move the the left hand side to the right and the sum is 0, or divide and the sum is 1.